# How to check if array elements match some pattern (eg:XXXXYY)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

For example,I have array:

```
[1,2,3,2,2,2,1,2,3]
```

, which matches the pattern XXXXYY because it has (at least) four '2' and two '1', but my question is, how to I check if the array matches such pattern? I tried:

```js
const arr=[1,2,3,2,2,2,1,3,2];
const pattern=[4,2];
let m=new Map();
for(const num of arr){
  if(!m[num]){
    m[num]=0;
  }
  m[num]++;
}

let i=0;
let isMatch=true;
for(const key in m){
  if(m[key]<pattern[i]){
    isMatch=false;
  }
  i++;
}
console.log(isMatch);
```

But isMatch is false. Is there any simpler method to do this?

Comment: simpler? you mean "correct" - because your method is fundamentally flawed m will be 1:2, 2:4, 3:2 - so your for loop is getting 2, 4, 2 for m[key]... and becuase 2<4, isMatch is false after the first iteration -surely you want to check if there's at least one distinct value in map that is >= the values in pattern

Comment: So, this problem states whether there are elements of `n` different kinds with expected frequency. If yes, then the given pattern is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could count the values and then take the sorted counts and check against the sorted pattern.

```js
var DESC = (a, b) => b - a,
    array = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2],
    pattern = [4, 2],
    count = Array
        .from(array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map).values())
        .sort(DESC),
    check = pattern
        .sort(DESC)
        .every((c, i) => count[i] >= c);
    
console.log(check);        
console.log(count);
```